# Resque job not being queued according to resque_spec but is available in job list

Tags: ruby, rspec, resque

I have the following test in rspec

```
it "should add the item to the resque queue" do
    post :run, id: report.id
    resque_job = Resque.peek(:default_queue)
    expect(resque_job).to be_present
    puts "Job is #{resque_job}"
    expect(ReportMapWorker).to have_queue_size_of(1)
    expect(ReportMapWorker).to have_queued(report.id).in(:default_queue)
end
```

The puts statement prints out the following:

```
Job is [{"class"=>"ReportMapWorker", "args"=>["1537"]}]
```

It is failing on the final expectation. Any ideas or suggestions as to where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the details of the failure (what was the result versus the expected value) and also how are you enqueuing the job in `post :run`? Trying to match it to known uses of in https://github.com/leshill/resque_spec/blob/master/spec/resque_spec/matchers_spec.rb

Comment: I have had this resolved by a friend who noted it should be: expect(ReportMapWorker).to have_queued(report.id.to_s).in(:default_queue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that the id is being added to the queue as a string, so when the expectation is expecting [1537] on the queue it should be expecting ["1537"]. Updating the code assertion to:

```
expect(ReportMapWorker).to have_queued(report.id.to_s).in(:default_queue)
```

works and the expectation passes.